# Remove the border of an html input field

Tags: html, input, colors, yii2, border

Is there a way to change the color and remove the border of an html inputfield?

```
echo Html::activeInput('text',$modelFahrtkostenItem, "[{$i}]nummer", $options = ['disabled' => true,'border'=> 'none']);
```

Comment: Use CSS. [Have a look at these answers](https://www.google.nl/search?q=yii2+border+site:stackoverflow.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you forgot to put "border" into "style"

```
echo Html::activeInput('text',$modelFahrtkostenItem, "[{$i}]nummer", $options = ['disabled' => true,'style' => ['border'=> 'none']]);
```